# Realizar un foreach, dentro de otro foreach para datos json, con laravel y Ajax

Tags: javascript, laravel, ajax, json, array

Estoy trabajando con laravel 5.6 y poseo una base de datos, donde una de sus columnas posee formato `json`, y se aprecia de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde el Backend, mi ruta es:

```html
Route::get('/perfil/ventas/obtener-opcionmetadata', 'SalesController@getOptionMetadata')->name('obtener.opcionmetadata');
```

En mi Controlador, poseo el método `getOptionMetadata`, del cual está así:

```html
public function getOptionMetadata(Request $request)
    {       
        $SubCategoriaId = $request->input('SubCategoriaId');
        $opcMetadatas = DB::table('opcion_metadata')
                ->join('metadata', 'metadata.id', '=', 'opcion_metadata.idMetadata')
                ->join('subcategorias','subcategorias.id','=','metadata.idSubCategoria')
                ->select('metadata.tipoMetadata','opcion_metadata.id','opcion_metadata.idMetadata','opcion_metadata.opcion','opcion_metadata.modalidad')->where('idSubCategoria',$SubCategoriaId)->get(); 

//SE REALIZA UN JOIN PARA SOLICITAR A VARIAS TABLAS, ES IRRELEVANTE.

        $response = ['data' => $opcMetadatas];  
        return response()->json($response);
       
    }
```

Y en el Frontend, estoy trabajando con una plantilla blade y con Ajax, donde al cambiar un "select", me debería traer la consulta mediante ajax.

Mi Ajax lo tengo de esta manera:

```js
idSubCategoria.change(function(){   //NOMBRE DEL BOTÓN SELECT

            var SubCategoriaId = $(this).val();
            seleccionarMetadata.empty();
            idContent.hide();
            
            if (SubCategoriaId) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{ route('obtener.opcionmetadata')}}",
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: { SubCategoriaId: SubCategoriaId },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (response) {                     
                     idContent.show(400);
                     $.each(response.data, function (key,value) {
                      $("#Metadatas").append("    <div>"+value.tipoMetadata+"</div><div>"+value.opcion+"</div>")

                        }); 
                    }
                });
```

Como pueden notar, al traer la respuesta mediante Ajax, se genera un `$.each`, para traer cada valor. De esta manera funciona bien, ya que obtengo los valores que estoy solicitando, el problema que estoy teniendo, es que poseo una columna con formato json, entonces me trae todo de esta manera:

Lo que se ve en la imagen es el resultado de esto:

```
$.each(response.data, function (key,value) {
      **$("#Metadatas").append("<div>"+value.tipoMetadata+"</div><div>"+value.opcion+"</div>")**
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que busco, es que se pueda ver así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir, que dentro del `$.each`, exista otro `$.each` para `+value.opcion+` (Eso lo que creo que debo hacer) para que me pueda quitar esos valores sin las comillas, sin los corchetes y sin las comas.

La verdad llevo días estancado con esto, espero su ayuda. Gracias!

Comment: Prueba parsearlo a un objeto javascript, o a un array en este caso. Con jquery `var arr = $.parseJSON( value.opcion );` o javascript `var arr = JSON.parse( value.opcion );`, luego podrá hacer el `$.each` sobre `arr`.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ   No me funciona, sólo trae [object Object], [object Object] ..

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ , de esta manera   `$.each(JSON.parse( value.opcion ), function(key,element) {     '<p>'+element+'</p>'; })+"");` funciona, pero me lo siguue trayendo con comas, existe la forma de poder separarlos o no se puede?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes parsearlo a un objeto javascript, o a un array en este caso. Con jquery var `$.parseJSON( value.opcion );` o javascript var `JSON.parse( value.opcion );`, luego podrá hacer el `$.each` sobre el resultado.
Para que se entienda: De la base de datos recuperas un `string`, que con `$.parseJSON` o `JSON.parse` lo conviertes a un `array` javascript. Como es un `array`, tendrás que iterar para imprimir cada elemento, por ejemplo con `JSON.parse`:

```js
let response = {};
response.data = [
  {
    tipoMetadata: 'algun tipo',
    opcion: "[\"JPG\", \"PNG\"]",
  },
  {
    tipoMetadata: 'otro tipo',
    opcion: "[\"GIF\", \"MP4\"]",
  },
];

$.each(response.data, function (key,value) {
    let html = '';
    html += "<div>"+value.tipoMetadata+"</div>";
    html += "<div>";
    $.each(JSON.parse( value.opcion ), (key,element) => { 
      html += '<p>'+element+'</p>'; 
    });
    html += "</div>";
    $("#Metadatas").append(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Metadatas"></div>
```

O con `$.parseJSON` es lo mismo:

```js
    let response = {};
    response.data = [
      {
        tipoMetadata: 'algun tipo',
        opcion: "[\"JPG\", \"PNG\"]",
      },
      {
        tipoMetadata: 'otro tipo',
        opcion: "[\"GIF\", \"MP4\"]",
      },
    ];

    $.each(response.data, function (key,value) {
        let html = '';
        html += "<div>"+value.tipoMetadata+"</div>";
        html += "<div>";
        $.each($.parseJSON( value.opcion ), (key,element) => { 
          html += '<p>'+element+'</p>'; 
        });
        html += "</div>";
        $("#Metadatas").append(html);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Metadatas"></div>
```

Comment: Gracias por darte el tiempo, la verdad me ayudo mucho tu código, realmente era lo que buscaba.. muchas gracias!

Comment: Vale, me alegra que te sirviera.